# add file to listview but show only the name inside my list

Tags: c#, winforms

in my application i am add file into my list box (my list box contain 3 column):

```
lvFiles.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
{ 
    (new FileInfo(filePath)).FullName, duration, "Waiting"
}));
```

`lvFiles.Items[i].Text` show me only the file name and i need the whole path

i want the option to show in my Listview only the file name: `new FileInfo(filePath)).Name`
but when i call to my class who need the full path: `myClass = new myClass(lvFiles.Items[i].Text);` in this case i want to send the whole file path: `new FileInfo(filePath)).FullName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property of the control. Set the Text to `FileInfo.Name` and set the `Tag` for `ListViewItem` to the full path. Like:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] {FileInfo(filePath)).Name, duration, "Waiting"});
item.Tag= FileInfo(filePath)).FullName;
lvFiles.Items.Add(item);
```

and then later

```
myClass = new myClass(lvFiles.Items[i].Tag.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add one more column for Only File name. And retrive the data from that column. Full File path Column can be hided if not required.